# keyboard.play function not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, keyboard-events

When calling the function with list of events it does nothing.

I've tried to save it to file or somehow share the variable but nothing has worked so far.

This is `record.py` which records pressed keys and saves them to file

```
import keyboard
import pickle

with open('keys.txt','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(keyboard.record(until='*'),f)
```

And here is `script.py` which loads pressed keys from file and presses them again

```
import keyboard
import pickle

with open('keys.txt','rb') as f:
    keyboard.play(pickle.load(f))
```

It doesn't show up any errors, but it does nothing - it should type what was saved in the file but it doesn't.

Comment: Do you understand what `open('file.txt', 'wb')`'s `'wb'` stands for? This makes it a binary file. You can't simply write bytes to a file and expect text from it. Note `pickle` just makes an object into a binary stream (bytes object) and can return an object from that stream again.

Comment: I needed to save list of events into file and this is the only way I found of doing it

Comment: The pickle.load(f) does its job, it loads correct list, but the function somehow does nothing.

Comment: Which function 'does nothing'?

Comment: keyboard.play() doesn't press or do anything, it types nothing. If I change the code to just write out the list made by pickle.load(f), it writes the correct list - list full of keyboard events, so there's no mistake in that

Comment: Hmm... That means that it's something in the keyboard library. I'm not too sure about stuff in `keyboard`.

Comment: Yeah seems weird.How would you go about this? Program that records keys pressed - but with exact timings - then saves them and replays that?

Comment: Not sure... If `keyboard.record` returns a list, it should be fine. I'm going to test it out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting "useless" functions, that don't really achieve anything. The record.py stays the same, I changed the script.py just like this:

```
import keyboard
import pickle

keyboard.start_recording()
keyboard.stop_recording()

with open('keys.txt','rb') as f:
    keyboard.play(pickle.load(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the events from keyboard into a list first.

record.py

```
import keyboard as k
import pickle as p
events = k.record(until = '*')
with open('events.txt', mode = 'wb') as file:
    p.dump(events, file)
```

script.py

```
import keyboard as k
import pickle as p
with open('events.txt', mode = 'rb') as file:
    events = p.load(file)
# end with
k.replay(events)
```

Comment: Hmm... Are you running this with IDLE?

Comment: It does... Did keyboard install properly?

Comment: Hmm. I've tested it. When you restart the Shell, playing it again doesnt focus on the Shell. Looks like it's focusing on the desktop...

Comment: Yup... I've tried that too. It opened the first thing on my taskbar, but it doesn't do anything more. I'll check out some other questions like this...

Comment: I think keyboard is not to blame... the pickle module might be changing things in some way or another.