# how do I store keyboard.record to a txt file and call it with keyboard.play

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros

I am trying to create a macro that i can call in python , the macro would record what buttons i pressed , how long i pressed them for, and the time between button presses

i want to be able to store the macro in a txt file so i can call it back with another function later on in time

this was the basic idea i thought off since i can use `rk = keyboard.record(until ='Esc')` then after i done recording the macro i use `keyboard.play(rk, speed_factor=1)` , that concept i just described works wonderfull, but i want to be able to store the `rk = keyboard.record(until ='Esc')` into a txt file and then be able to read it from the file and play it

this code below is the idea i was trying to achieve but it doesn't work

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import keyboard
import time


def recorder():
    rk = keyboard.record(until ='Esc')
    file = open("test.txt", "a")
    for r in rk:
        data = str(r) + "\n"
        file.write(data)

def play_back():
    file = open("test.txt", "r")
    lists = []

    Lines = file.readlines()
    
    count = 0
    # Strips the newline character
    for line in Lines:
        count += 1
        if line[-1] == "\n":
            lists.append(line[:-1])
        else:
            lists.append(line)

    print(lists)

    keyboard.play(lists, speed_factor=1)
```

this is the error code that appears after i call on the `play_back()` function

```
['KeyboardEvent(s down)', 'KeyboardEvent(s up)', 'KeyboardEvent(s down)', 'KeyboardEvent(s up)', 'KeyboardEvent(a down)', 'KeyboardEvent(a up)', 'KeyboardEvent(a down)', 'KeyboardEvent(a up)', 'KeyboardEvent(d down)', 'KeyboardEvent(d up)', 'KeyboardEvent(d down)', 'KeyboardEvent(d up)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace down)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace up)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace down)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace up)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace down)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace up)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace down)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace up)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace down)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace up)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace down)', 'KeyboardEvent(backspace up)', 'KeyboardEvent(esc down)', 'KeyboardEvent(left down)', 'KeyboardEvent(left up)', 'KeyboardEvent(down down)', 'KeyboardEvent(down up)', 'KeyboardEvent(right down)', 'KeyboardEvent(right up)', 'KeyboardEvent(right down)', 'KeyboardEvent(right up)', 'KeyboardEvent(s down)', 'KeyboardEvent(s up)', 'KeyboardEvent(s down)', 'KeyboardEvent(s up)', 'KeyboardEvent(d down)', 'KeyboardEvent(d up)', 'KeyboardEvent(a down)', 'KeyboardEvent(a up)', 'KeyboardEvent(s down)', 'KeyboardEvent(s up)', 'KeyboardEvent(esc down)']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program1\testing122.py", line 33, in <module>
    play_back()
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program1\testing122.py", line 31, in play_back
    keyboard.play(lists, speed_factor=1)
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program1\venv001\Lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 1060, in play
    last_time = event.time
                ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'time'. Did you mean: 'title'?
```

so just to summarize : I want to record a macro of my exact button presses including the timings within (how much I press a button for, how much time time between 2 button presses) i then want to be able to call that record with a function in python , my approach here might be wrong so i would love your inputs

Thanks in advance

update:
with the help of LhasaDad he came up with this bit of code that records the keyboard inputs and puts them in a txt file and call them back with the`play_back()` function

```
def recorder():
    rk = keyboard.record(until ='Esc')
    file = open("test.txt", "w")

    for r in rk:
        # serialize the object to json format
        data = r.to_json() + "\n"
        file.write(data)

    file.close()


def play_back():
    lists = []
    with open("test.txt", "r") as file:

        lines = file.readlines()

        # Strips the newline character
        for line in lines:
            # recreate the object from the json dict by loading the json and
            # use as keyword parameters to KeyboardEvent
            lists.append(keyboard.KeyboardEvent(**json.loads(line)))

    print(lists)

    keyboard.play(lists, speed_factor=1)
```

now the problem now is a wierd one if i run the code by calling the`recorder()` function followed by the `play_back()` like this

```
recorder()
play_back()
```

it works as intended but if i run the `recorder()` function first and record my inputs and let the recorder function finish and the program finish running all its code

example

```
recorder()
```

so am only running the recorder function that saves it to a file,
then i try to run it later with the play_back after the first program is done

```
play_back()
```

it doesnot work

Comment: You saved the string representation of the KeyboardEvent class object.   the play needs an actual object.   you need to recreate Keyboard event objects.   you might be able to use something like pickle to serialize a list of KeyboardEvents (not string-ified events).  then unpickle that and play it.

Comment: i think i semi understand what you just said is it possible that you show my code that could do what you just said as am new to coding

Comment: adding an answer with updated code.  note you need to import json package as I have added it to the code I am posting.

Comment: bit of  a python trick on the recreate of the object using the '**' operation to take the dictionary and have it passed off as named parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have found the answer , it turns out there is a problem withing the `keyboard.record` and `keyboard.play` for some reason as mentioned in this stack overflow article over here

[keyboard.play function not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029314/keyboard-play-function-not-working-correctly)

here is the solution

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import keyboard
import time
import json
import pickle


def recorder():
    with open('keys.txt','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(keyboard.record(until='*'),f)


def play_back():
    keyboard.start_recording()
    keyboard.stop_recording()

    with open('keys.txt','rb') as f:
        keyboard.play(pickle.load(f))

play_back()
```

in the above example am using pickle and I have already used the `record()` function to record the actions
`keyboard.start_recording` and `keyboard.stop_recording` donot impact the code but for some random reason it makes it work

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/283
This is an open issue on the keyboard repository. Looks like `keyboard.play()` does not initialize the OS-specific modules required to interface with the keyboard (or maybe there's something else going on, I'm not sure).

Comment: Good find.   Note, the original code without the changes I noted for you would not have produced the results you wanted.   pickle dump/load or the to_json/json_loads is still needed for the original code you had.   Pickle does have its own limitations.  it looks like they provided the to_json for serialization.

Comment: note this works but try not to name the file .txt name it anything else as i heard it causes problems

Comment: i named it .pickle later .txt was just to test if it works ty for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code with a changes to serialize as json and use the serialized json to recreate the object.  Not the comments I added by the changes I made.

```
import keyboard

import json


def recorder():
    rk = keyboard.record(until='Esc')

    with open("test.txt", "a") as file:
        for r in rk:
            # serialize the object to json format
            data = r.to_json() + "\n"
            file.write(data)


def play_back():
    lists = []
    with open("test.txt", "r") as file:

        lines = file.readlines()

        # Strips the newline character
        for line in lines:
            # recreate the object from the json dict by loading the json and
            # use as keyword parameters to KeyboardEvent
            lists.append(keyboard.KeyboardEvent(**json.loads(line)))

    print(lists)

    keyboard.play(lists, speed_factor=1)
```

Comment: do i need to change .txt in the recorder and play_back functions

Comment: not sure what you are asking?

Comment: btw,  you will need to close the file you are adding to before reading from it.   you might want to check in to the 'with' function in python.  that will allow you to open the file and have it autoclose after you leave the with block.

Comment: if you mean do you need to change the extension of the file.   no, that is not important to your code. its just part of the file name.

Comment: i see, one last thing 'lists.append(KeyboardEvent(**json.loads(line)))' is showing me error for KeyboardEvent and what did you mean by this comment # use as keyword parms to KeyboardEvent

Comment: what was the error?   I may have to fix my code. I did not try it yet :-)

Comment: well first error was in the recorder function its not r.to+jason its r.to_jason

Comment: secound thing is the KeyboardEvent in the play_back function is saying not defined

Comment: to be more precise this is the error that appears from running play_back() function
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program1\testing122.py", line 35, in <module> 
    play_back()
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program1\testing122.py", line 29, in play_back
    lists.append(KeyboardEvent(**json.loads(line)))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'KeyboardEvent' is not defined
```

Comment: ok, will edit and update the code.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: so now there is no more errors .. , but it doesnot type anything that is recorded XD

Comment: so it does record it and print it out.   I just tried it with adding a call to the record function folllowed by a call to the playback function.    If you want the stuff you are typing in to echo out then the keyboard.record function is not the one you want.

Comment: when i copy every thing under the play_back function and put it in the record function it works just fine, but when i do it seperatly i doesnot type anything , why is that

Comment: i see what you mean but then having it in a txt file or saved is usless cuz i cannot call it technically from the txt file without doing a record function right before

Comment: is there a way we can get the desired outcome some other way

Comment: So, not sure how you are calling your two functions.  that was not in the original code.  but the record() function is blocking and will take the input till you hit escape key.  then the other stuff causes it to come out.

Comment: is there a way we can get the desired outcome some other way

Comment: there is a start_recording() and stop_recording() function in keyboard module that may do more the behavior you want.

Comment: what i mean is when i run the record function and the play_back function back to back it works just fine but if i run the record function only and record the inputs and the code all the code has been executed then i try to run the play_back function only it does nothing

Comment: not sure exactly what behavior is desired but you may need to play with other functions in that module to get what you want.   hope this was some help.

Comment: i hope i am making sense

Comment: a little but not sure how you are running them so not sure how you are getting the result.   you might want to edit your original question to add that info.

Comment: i have edited the orginal post